# When does a thread get it's associated access token?

Tags: c, windows, security

my problem could also be stated as "why am I getting ERROR_NO_TOKEN from call to OpenThreadToken"?

The faulting piece is:

```
hMainThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, threadID);

if (hMainThread == NULL)
{
    printf("Couldn't open thread. : %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}

if (!OpenThreadToken(hMainThread, TOKEN_READ, FALSE, &hMainThreadToken))
{
    printf("Couldn't open thread token: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
```

I am getting the second error line with 1008. The owner process of the thread is started with `runas /user:someoneelse`

I believe I understand something wrong about impersonation. Does runas not impersonate? Also funny thing is that I went trying this code on several main thread IDs in my system and it worked for main thread of taskmgr.exe.. So the code is probably ok and so is the behaviour of Windows leaving us with me thinking "If you use runas, your main thread automaticaly gets an acces token set.. right?" - which is probably the only thing that is wrong here. So when does the thread get it's asociated access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RunAs does not use thread impersonation, the whole process runs as the specified user.

When OpenThreadToken fails you usually just fall back to `OpenProcessToken`.

See [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN for the ways a thread can impersonate a user/client. `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient` is perhaps the most commonly used function, especially when a service needs to impersonate the client.